# Heterogeneity test in meta-analysis

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, meta-regression, heterogeneity

In a random effect meta-analysis model with one categorical independent variable $\theta_{ij}=\theta_i+s_j+\epsilon_j$, where $\theta_{ij}$ is the observed effect size in category $i$ in study $j$, $\theta_i$ is the mean effect size in category $i$, $s_j$ is the random study effect, and $\epsilon_j$ is the within study error (or sampling error). We often further assume that $s_i$ follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\tau^2$. $\epsilon_j$ is also normally distributed and its variance ($\sigma^2$) is calculated from primary literature and is assumed to be known when fitting the model.

In a model like this, meta-analysis software, such as metafor in R, can perform two heterogeneity test. The first is testing if among study heterogeneity is 0, that is, $\tau=0$. This is done by computing a Cochran's $Q=\sum w_i(\theta_{ij}-\hat{\theta_i})^2$. Here, $w_i=1/\sigma^2$ and $\hat{\theta_i}$ is the weighted average ($w_i$ as the weight) of all $\theta_{ij}$ within the $i$th group. Meta-analysis text book often says that Q is **asymptopically** chi-square distributed under the null hypothesis $\tau=0$.

The second homogeneity test is whether all $\theta_i$ are equal. This is done by computing a $Q=\sum w^*_i(\hat{\theta_i}-\hat{\theta})^2$, where $\hat{\theta_i}$ is the weighted ($w^*_i=1/(\hat{\tau^2}+\sigma^2)$) average of all $\theta_{ij}$ within the $i$he category and $\hat{\theta}$ is the weighted overall mean. Again, Q follows a Chi-square distribution.

The questions I have are

1. In the first test, Why is Q asymptotically chi-square, not exactly Chi-square? We know for a normally distributed random variable, $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ follows chi-square distribution. Q is essentially the same. Is it the weighted average that makes it asymptotically, but not exactly, Chi-square?
2. Is the heterogeneity test for $\tau$ still valid in general for a linear mixed effect model? In a linear mixed model, we usually don't know $\sigma$ and have to estimate it using "ML" or "REML". Does this break the Chi-square distribution of Q? I have never seen the Q statistics for testing random effect in a linear mixed model text book. We know that likelihood ratio or Wald test for random effect tends to be conservative. If this Q statistics works in general, why isn't it adopted as a general test for linear mixed models?
3. For the second heterogeneity test about the categorical predictor, is it just a Wald test? We know that Wald test or likelihood ratio test are anti-conservative in linear mixed model. Many text book recommends conditional F test (with df corrections) or simulation based inference. Is such anti-conservative nature still a concern for meta-analysis model? I don't know whether the fact that $\sigma$ is given to the model as a known quantity alleviate such problem.

I have read a few meta-analysis textbook and search online but cannot find detailed explanations for these technical details. Any insights or references would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have done more reading on primary literature since posting the questions. I want to post what I have learnt since then and hopefully that might be helpful for someone else. I cannot guarantee that these new findings are absolutely correct. So please feel free to comment and correct any wrong understandings here.

1. If we treat $\sigma$ as known, $Q$ follows an exact Chi-square distribution. The proof is similar to proving $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ follows Chi-square distribution. Using weighted average in the calculation does not break the Chi-square distribution. However, in practice, $\sigma$ is not actually known. It is calculated based on data in primary literature and treated as known. This is what makes the distribution asymptotic. This [1982 paper by Hedges](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.92.2.490) seems to be the first paper that address the distribution property of the Q statistic.
2. It only works in the settings of meta-analysis because $\sigma$ is treated as known. In linear mixed model, $\sigma$ is unknown and has to be estimated. If we use the estimated $\sigma$ in calculating Q, the Q statistics does not have Chi-square distribution any more. In fact, if $\sigma$ is estimated in the absence of any random effect (i.e. in a linear model), Q is actually always n-1.
3. It is indeed a Wald test. And Wald test tends to be anti-conservative in linear mixed model. Because Wald test is based on asymptotic theory, sample size influences its performance. I think this is why the anti-conservative problem is less severe in meta-analysis. In a meta-analysis, the random effect $s_j$ is for each $\theta_{ij}$ and thus we have a large sample size to estimate $\tau$. For example, if we compiled 100 effect size estimates for a meta-analysis without any moderator, we have 99 degrees of freedom to estimate $\tau$. In a normal linear mixed model, we often don't have that many samples to estimate random effect. For example, we may do an experiment in a few randomly chosen fields or conduct an experiment in several randomly chosen schools. This makes the anti-conservative property of the Wald test a more severe concern in general for linear mixed model. However, such anti-conservative problem is recognized in meta-analysis literature as well. Adjustments such as the Knapp-Hartung method has been proposed to at least partially resolve this issue.